# Indirect pointer overwriting - how does it overwrite the return address?

Tags: buffer-overflow

So I've read that if you're unable to overwrite the return address directly through an overflow, you can still overwrite the return address indirectly through a pointer.

I know it works by using overflow to overwrite a local variable. Then if there's a pointer that is dereferenced to the value of that local variable then apparently it can overwrite the return address? This is the part I'm struggling to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most perfect way of looking at this, but hopefully it gives you an idea of what's possible:

```c
void myFunc() {
  int* ptr = (whatever the code was pointing to);
  int numToBePutInPtr;
  char aString[10];

  // INSERT HERE some way of inputting into aString. To perform the attack
  // input 10 useless bytes, then the address of the code you want to get run,
  // then the address of the return address on the stack

  *ptr = numToBePutInPtr;
}
```

When that last line gets run, instead of the original value of `numToBePutInPtr` going into `*ptr`, it's the address of the code you want to get run. And because you overwrote `ptr` to actually point to where the return address lies on the stack, the return address will be replaced with the address to the code you want to run.

The main differentiator between this attack and the more basic overflow-to-overwrite-return-address attack is that the more simple guards of the stack won't catch you overflowing past the local variables (you're "jumping over" that check by just using a pointer). However, this is still heavily guarded against with other checks.